# correct way to "porting" docstrings of other methods/functions/objects into a class?

Tags: python, oop, docstring

Here is what I am doing:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """
        docstring of Foo.
        """
        self.sum = bar(**kwargs)
    __init__.__doc__ += bar.__doc__

def bar(a, b):
    """
    docstring of bar.
    a: int
    b: int
    """
    print(a+b)
```

What I wanted to do:
There are some calculations defined in `bar`. The class `Foo` uses `bar`. I would like to avoid duplicate code, i.e. I would like to avoid writing for example `a: int` in `Foo`. Thus I am trying to "port" (is this the right term?) the docstring of `bar` into `Foo` by adding that line `__init__.__doc__ += bar.__doc__`.

Is this the *right* way to do this? Am I hacking? Imagine `Foo` is part of API, whereas `bar` is the backstage subroutine. What's the *correct* way of displaying the docstring of `bar` to the user?

Comment: This is not "duplicating code".  The whole point of documentation is to make things clear.  You're talking about one cut-and-paste operation in your editor.

Comment: Then, later when you update `bar` and its docstring, you'd need to update all the `Foo` that uses `bar`. Imaging in a large project there are several layers, e.g. `Oof` using `Foo`... then each layer's docstring need to be manually edited? @TimRoberts

Comment: RIght.  People that want to use your `Foo` class shouldn't have to go looking for `bar`'s signature.  It should be right in front of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `bar` before `Foo`. In your current configuration, the name `bar` does not exist in the global namespace when the class body is executed.

You might consider adding a newline or some sort of divider between the docs:

```
__init__.__doc__ += '\n' +  bar.__doc__
```

Documentation is rarely read directly from a docstring. A better answer would be to use a tool like [sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org) to generate useable documentation in a format like HTML or PDF. Instead of copy-and-pasting the documentation of `bar` into that of `Foo.__init__`, you could link to it. This would have the advantage that you would not need to rearrange the objects in the global namespace.

The popular plotting library [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/index.html) is a great example of your exact usecase. It has many functions, like [`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html), which passes through is remaining arguments (`fig_kw`) to [`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html). Looking at the source for the [docstring](https://matplotlib.org/stable/_modules/matplotlib/pyplot.html#subplots), we see:

> ```
> **fig_kw
>     All additional keyword arguments are passed to the
>     `.pyplot.figure` call.
> ```

The backticks generate a link in sphinx. You can write the docstring of `Foo.__init__` in a similar manner:

```
"""
docstring of Foo.

Parameters
----------
**kwargs
    Arguments passed through to `bar`.
"""
```

Comment: Thank you. So the "correct" way is not to do something like `__init__.__doc__ += '\n' +  bar.__doc__` nor re-writing docstrings of `a` and `b` in `Foo`, but rather leave it as is and use backticks for sphinx instead. Of course when a user queries `help(Foo)` no details of `kwargs` would show but they are expected to read the docs generated by sphinx.

Comment: @Alex if `help` told you to read the docs for `bar` you could always do `help(bar)`.